# TemplateDoesNotExist when trying to override template name in detail view

Tags: python, django

I am following django 2.0 tutorial "2.6.2 Use generic views: Less code is better" and try to convert functions views to class views.

It throws such an error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/1/results/
polls/question_detail.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/results/
Django Version: 2.0.4
```

I checked the code with the official materials

```
class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template = 'polls/results.html'

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        #Redisplay the question voting form
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question':question,
            'error_message':"You did'nt select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

The errors occurs when I attempt to submit the vote:

[image]

The `polls/detail.html` template works properly when come with the functions views:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}
  <p>
    <strong>{{ error_message }}</strong>
  </p>
{% endif %}

<form  action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all  %}
  <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice {{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{  choice.id }}"/>
  <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label> <br>

{% endfor %}
<input type="submit"  value="Vote"/>
</form>
```

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: Please post the `urls.py` from the app **polls**. The error is obvious: the view looks for the template `polls/question_detail.html`, which doesn't exist. That's why we need to see the `urls.py` in order to check which view is called when the url `/polls/1/results/` is requested.

Comment: Also nothing in your code includes the `polls/question_detail.html` so it is obviously a different view/url

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues, no, the `ResultsView` shown in the question will default to `polls/question_detail.html`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, a `DetailView` for the `Question` model in the `polls` app uses the template `polls/question_detail.html`.

You need to use `template_name` if you want to override that. You have set `template`, which will have no effect. It should be:

```
class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'
    ...
```